# SSRS : How to hide the value in the parameter while entering the data

Tags: sql, reporting-services

His there a way to hide data when entering the value for a parameter in ssrs reporting

For example my report has  a parameter box where the user needs to give sensitive id in the parameter box for displaying his report. so while entering the value for the parameter the user should not able to view the data entered in the parameter instead it should show some special characters.

example **********

when we enter a password we would not be able to see the value in the same way can we do it in ssrs

Comment: No. Not available in SSRS, don't know about custom codes.

Comment: If you feel like hacking up your SSRS web files (css, aspx), you could add some Javascript code to look for parameter textboxes that resemble a certain name (such as "HIDE"), and if so, change them to a "password" control.  Not sure if you could get away with embedding that within the RDL (I've only done this site-wide), but worth a shot.